# Is the French public opinion more favorable to Muslims than to Jews?

Tags: france, public-opinion, minorities

It's been suggested in an answer to a [related question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/is-there-a-sustained-difference-in-public-views-on-the-israel-palestine-issue-be?noredirect=1#50008) that the French public opinion is more favorable to Muslims than to Jews (due in part to the larger presence of Muslims in France). I for one think the issue is different enough than attitudes on Israel vs Palestinians, but I'm curious if any polls in France actually find a more negative French attitude towards Jews than towards Muslims.

Comment: FWIW I don't think anyone in the other thread actually made the claim that that public opinion in France is more favorable about Muslims than Jews. More like, Muslim perspectives have had a greater impact on French public opinion than American, and that has a lot to do with the much larger proportion of Muslims in France than the US.

Comment: @Colin: if the answer (to the other question) is along the lines of "they care about the poor bastards", i.e. sympathy despite disdain, or even "they worry about more Muslim immigration" (because Muslims are viewed negatively), it wasn't made exactly clear in either your comment or the (now deleted) answer. "A greater impact" is a rather unclear claim... greater could be negative... it's less often the case that one dislikes X but agrees with X on something nonetheless.

Comment: The poll that you cite still shows 72% of French have a favorable view of Muslims. Those that have greater sympathy for the Palestinian cause than the Israeli would largely but not exclusively fall within this group. Also, it is perfectly possible, even common, to self report favorable views of Jews and Muslims, not know much about the Israeli-Palestinian conflict, and fall into a view which accepts the propaganda of one side or the other.

Answer (score 7):

At least in one 2014 [Pew poll](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2015/01/14/french-have-positive-views-of-both-jews-muslims/) the answer seems to be that Muslims are more negatively viewed in France than Jews.

[image]

By the way, publishing the results of such polls in France (especially when they get to detailed questions) is [not terribly popular](https://www.france24.com/en/20160201-daughter-marry-muslim-poll-france-jewish-racism-religion-islamaphobia).

It's actually hard to find some detail questions that were comparable in that latter [poll](https://www.ipsos.com/sites/default/files/files-fr-fr/doc_associe/presentation_globale_enquete_fjf.pdf) (as it focused on prejudices, which differ in details regarding Muslims and Jews in France), but this is interesting enough perhaps: far more French said their minorities from Muslims countries were badly integrated in France (compared to Jews), and they also said the blame generally falls on the minorities (but even more so on the Muslim ones).

[image]

There was also a question on marriage, in which the subject's child marrying a Muslim was more negatively viewed than marrying a Jew.

[image]

Comment: One problem that vexes the media and elites is this: Anti-semitisim in France, to the extent that it exists in the native population, is passive.  People may think bad things, but don't act on them.  The actual "kinetic" anti-semetic incidents in France originate with the poorly assimilated Muslim population.  Local Jews get attacked, the cops tell them, "well, don't wear any outward signs in public", and the result is an exodus of French Jews to Israel.  This doesn't get emphasized in reporting.

Comment: @JohnK That's not true, there are also examples of antisemitic incidents from other parts of the French population (e.g. [this](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profanation_du_cimeti%C3%A8re_juif_de_Sarre-Union)). But since antisemitic violence from people perceived as immigrant youth (who are often actually born in France and neither believers nor practicing Muslims) fits a stereotype and plays into the hostility mentioned in this answer, it is often emphasized by commentators.

Comment: Incidentally, in spite of the (very real) prejudice documented in the polls cited above, there is a lot of evidence that the Muslim minority and/or people whose family came from a Muslim-majority country are more assimilated in France than elsewhere in Europe or in the US.

Comment: I said in an earlier comment, on an answer that was since deleted, that the French have not done a good job of assimilating their Muslim population. I've been to Paris and have been warned about areas to stay away from. There are plenty of well assimilated Muslim immigrants but in the aggregate there is still a problem. Jews aren't bailing for Israel because the natives have all of a sudden started attacking them when things were fine until 10 or 15 years ago.  Something changed.  The elites do not want to face the problem.  I'm in Canada where Muslims integrate fine overall.

Comment: @JohnK I saw that message and I think it's also ill-informed. Your comment mixes up so many things that it's difficult to know where to start. Let me note that being warned to stay away from some area isn't much of an evidence of anything. The thing elites have most difficulties facing is that Muslims integrate fine overall in France too. I am also beginning to wonder who counts as Muslim in your view? Regarding violence against Jews, something did change, not 10 or 15 years ago but in 2000.

Comment: @Relaxed: that's interesting. Do you have a source (for the Muslim minority being more assimilated in France than elsewhere)?