# Is there a party in Europe whose supporters show a high degree of sympathy towards Israel?

Tags: parties, israel, public-opinion, europe, comparative-politics

I find this plot over time of [US sympathy for Israel](https://www.people-press.org/2018/01/23/republicans-and-democrats-grow-even-further-apart-in-views-of-israel-palestinians/) rather fascinating, especially when broken down by US party.

[image]

One has to wonder how much of that is explained by ["conflict extension"](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/49718/does-the-year-2000-observation-that-issue-alignment-mainly-affected-the-us-polit) in recent times, but that's not the topic of my question.

What I'd like to know: **is there a country in Europe where a party's supporters express a similar level of sympathy toward Israel as the GOP's nowadays?**

I was able to find a [2014 poll](https://yougov.co.uk/topics/politics/articles-reports/2014/03/11/israel-and-palestine-whose-side-britain) (but not a graph over time) for the UK, which does find some fairly significant differences across parties, but the pro-Israeli sentiment on the UK right doesn't rise anywhere near the US levels...

[image]

I cannot find any stats for Germany (but per comments and answers below pointing to right-wing populist parties) a news search has [revealed](https://www.jns.org/anti-israel-vote-in-the-german-bundestag-spurs-criticism-of-germanys-mixed-israel-policies/) that the AfD has joined the [Free Democratic Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Democratic_Party_(Germany)) in a Bundestag effort to have Germany retract its support for UN resolutions condemning Israel. (See also the interesting story of [Henryk M. Broder](https://www.tabletmag.com/jewish-news-and-politics/279898/jewish-journalist-defending-german-far-right) .)

Comment: I'm not sure if you're aware of the fact that the Jewish voting bloc in the US is overwhelmingly Democratic.  It's mainly because US Jews have tended to be liberal-ish in outlook over the years, and traditions die hard.  There is a tension building now as the Democratic party moves farther and farther from support of Israel.  At some point something's gonna give and the Dems are going to lose their Jewish vote lock.

Comment: @JohnK I think you’re vastly overestimating how many Jews are willing to tolerate anti-semitism in exchange for deference to the government of Israel. There are certainly a number of Jews for whom this is a key issue, but it’s important to keep clear that the real audience for right-wing "support for Israel” has always been evangelical Christians.

Comment: Tolerate anti-semetism?  What?

Comment: One could argue that there are parties where anti-semitism thrives together with pro-israel sentiments. Reason being that as much as the typical European far-right populist dislikes Jews, he hates Arabs even more.

Comment: 79% is rather extreme, so if you are talking about one of the 2 top parties in a country in Europe, probably not.

Comment: My guess would be far-right populist parties. I don’t have any data to back this up though.

Comment: What does "similar level of sympathy" mean in this context? You'd be hard pressed to find any political party or organisation outside of Israel itself that is just as Israel-friendly as the US Republican party.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist: an answer could be "no, but the highest levels of sympathy seems to be in European country X, among supporters of party Y."

Comment: @JohnK You posited that the Republican party’s supposedly “pro-Israel” stance will eventually win over the support of large numbers of Jews. But Jews, like all people, care about many issues. They may care about Israel more than other groups, but not all in the same way. Many (most?) would even dispute that the administration’s actions are, in fact, pro-Israel, and any larger shift is not going to happen until they stop tolerating and engaging in anti-semitism, no matter what their Israel policy is

Comment: @divibisan you are right there.  Repubilcan leaders still associate with Louis Farrakhan.  Oh wait... wrong party... Anyway, Jews have voted Democrat because they have tended to be left of centre on social and economic issues and that was the natural fit, sufficient to overlook things like FDR refusing refugees.  Granted, in the 30s, anti-semetism was pretty broad based, even up here in Canada.

Comment: @Fizz I think your question is too broad. There are hundreds of parties in Europe and they all have different opinions on the IP-conflict. It can't be covered in a single answer. I encourage you to open a new question focusing on a specific European country - Germany, France, Poland, etc - that you are interested in.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist: I wasn't asking for a comprehensive survey of European countries here, just hoping someone would know an extreme example in Europe "close enough" to the US.